# Optional ByRef - wrong in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Public Function Foo(ByRef a As AClass, _
                    Optional ByRef b As BClass = Nothing, _ 
                    Optional ByRef c As CClass = Nothing) As XClass
```

> Error : Optional parameters must
>   specify a default value.

Was is Das?

Comment: You should almost definitely be using `ByVal`.

Comment: @SLaks: But I need ByRef

Comment: @serhio: Why? You almost definitely don't.

Comment: @SLaks: because I use "b" and "c" like an `out` (C#) value.

Comment: I just had `ByRef b As bclass As bclass = Nothing` (repeating as) sorry for question.

Comment: Seems very odd to me that you'd want to allow an actual reference to not be supplied for those parameters.  In that method, you have no way of differentiating whether someone called `Foo(myA, Nothing, Nothing)` or `Foo(myA, myB, myC)`.  As a result, it feels like you're going to end up creating bogus instances of b and c that may or may not be just thrown away when the method returns.  Addtionally, I'm kinda surprised that you can actually specify Nothing for a ByRef parameter in VB.

Comment: @Wes P: you have reason. *Seems* very odd

Comment: Just to make sure, you do know that you don't need to declare parameters as ByRef just to change the members of the object?  You only need to declare ByRef if you're changing the instance of the object. i.e. `b = new BClass` or `b = DifferentInstanceOfBClass`.  If all you're doing is `b.MyField = newValue` then ByVal will suffice and lessen the attrociticity (new word) of that code.

Comment: @Wes P: I change the instance of object. I pass a obj=Nothing value as parameter, and expect an initialised value as output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This compile fine for me with empty classes.  I seem to think you have you error in other line, or on define of the parameter classes.

```
Public Class Class1

    Public Function Foo(ByRef a As aclass, _
                        Optional ByRef b As bclass = Nothing, _
                        Optional ByRef c As cclass = Nothing) As xclass
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class

Public Class aclass    
End Class

Public Class bclass    
End Class

Public Class cclass    
End Class

Public Class xclass
End Class
```

Comment: Performed similar experiment and had no problem either, though I have to say anyone trying to get such code past me would be quickly shown the door.

Comment: I just had `ByRef b As bclass As bclass = Nothing` (repeating as) sorry for question

Comment: Reasons: 1) Single Responsibility Principle, I suspect Foo is doing far too much. 2) Obfuscation. ByRef parameters are a code smell at the best of times (just by looking at the calling code you can't tell that this parameter will be changed by the function). Optional ByRef parameters are worse again. 3) Unit testing. Testing this function and it's side effects is likely going to be a nightmare. I bet you ready money there's a better solution to your problem rather than a function that returns a result *and* modifies Zero, One or Two *optional* parameters, depending on how it's called.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: Thanks for analysis. As general remarks are good, but not in my concrete case.

Comment: @serhio: I speak with 20+ years experience developing real world software. Even without knowing your concrete case I can tell you there are 10 better ways of doing this. Do yourself a favour, ask another question looking for a "Best Practice" alternative to your function.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: you exaggerate. 10(!) better ways I have serious doubts about your words :)

Comment: OK 10 better ways **is** an exaggeration :), still I wouldn't do it this way :) Best of luck mate.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the pattern that you want to use I'd recommend creating an overload that doesn't require those parameters:

```
Public Function Foo(ByRef a As AClass) As XClass
    Return Foo(a, Nothing, Nothing)
End Function
Public Function Foo(ByRef a As AClass, ByRef b As BClass, ByRef c As CClass) As XClass
    '//Return XClass here
End Function
```

Comment: C# approach. not especially needed in VB.NET

Comment: No, this is definitely a VB approach.  C# would NEVER let you supply null values to a ref parameter.  I've never cared much for the idea of Optional parameters, so I'm more inclined toward overloads.  You really do end up with more explicit and cleaner code.

Comment: @serhio: actually optional parameters might be a source of errors.